# How to get count of Primary key by multiple columns and their categories in Vertica SQL?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have table as given below. (3 columns and 10 rows)

```
ID cat_1 cat_2
1001    High    High
1002    Mid High
1003    Mid High
1004    <null>  <null>
1005    <null>  Low
1006    High    High
1007    <null>  <null>
1008    High    Mid
1009    Low Low
1010    High    High
```

And I would want to calculate the count of ID for each of the columns. I don't want to run multiple queries. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

```
Category    cat_1   cat_2
High    4   5
Mid 2   1
Low 1   2
<null>  3   2
```

Currently, I only know to run multiple queries of group by statements (*"select cat_1, count(ID) from table group by 1"*). I know this approach is not the correct one. Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate.  Here is a general approach:

```
select cat, sum(cat_1), sum(cat_2)
from ((select cat_1 as cat, 1 as cat_1, 0 as cat_2
       from t
      ) union all
      (select cat_2, 0 as cat_1, 1 as cat_2
       from t
      )
     ) c
group by cat;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=60e2f5f6b17a4b3fe9ce53878e2a8683) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for responding. But I don't get it. Can you write the query for the sample data I have put? (I don't understand the 1s/0s you have used).

Comment: I added a db<>fiddle.  I'm not really sure how to explain `0` and `1`.  They are integers that I imagine you are familiar iwth.

Comment: Cool! Just worked it out for my data set. Learnt something new in SQL... thank you so much!